# JBoss 4.2.1 deployment issue on Windows 7 Professional

Tags: jboss

I have to move from Tomcat to JBoss 4.2.1. That's OK. 
 1. I downloaded this version from JBoss site.
 2. Unzipped it D:\JBoss\jboss\
 3. Then I started the run.bat (as admin) from D:\JBoss\jboss\bin but it fired up an exception. I tried to find solution in forums but without success and here where is I am now.

Hope someone could help.
Here is the result:

```
===============================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: D:\JBoss\jboss

  JAVA: C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -Dprogram.name=run.bat -server -Xms128m -Xmx512m -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000

  CLASSPATH: C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\lib\tools.jar;D:\JBoss\jboss\bin\run.jar

===============================================================================

18:11:23,004 INFO  [Server] Starting JBoss (MX MicroKernel)...
18:11:23,005 INFO  [Server] Release ID: JBoss [Trinity] 4.2.1.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_1_GA date=200707131605)
18:11:23,006 INFO  [Server] Home Dir: D:\JBoss\jboss
18:11:23,006 INFO  [Server] Home URL: file:/D:/JBoss/jboss/
18:11:23,007 INFO  [Server] Patch URL: null
18:11:23,007 INFO  [Server] Server Name: default
18:11:23,007 INFO  [Server] Server Home Dir: D:\JBoss\jboss\server\default
18:11:23,008 INFO  [Server] Server Home URL: file:/D:/JBoss/jboss/server/default/
18:11:23,008 INFO  [Server] Server Log Dir: D:\JBoss\jboss\server\default\log
18:11:23,008 INFO  [Server] Server Temp Dir: D:\JBoss\jboss\server\default\tmp
18:11:23,009 INFO  [Server] Root Deployment Filename: jboss-service.xml
18:11:23,177 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java version: 1.6.0_25,Sun Microsystems Inc.
18:11:23,177 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM 20.0-b11,Sun Microsystems Inc.
18:11:23,177 INFO  [ServerInfo] OS-System: Windows 7 6.1,x86
18:11:23,520 INFO  [Server] Core system initialized
18:11:24,886 INFO  [WebService] Using RMI server codebase: http://127.0.0.1:8083/
18:11:24,886 INFO  [Log4jService$URLWatchTimerTask] Configuring from URL: resource:jboss-log4j.xml
18:11:25,136 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] JBossTS Transaction Service (JTA version) - JBoss Inc.
18:11:25,136 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Setting up property manager MBean and JMX layer
18:11:25,259 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Starting recovery manager
18:11:25,303 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Recovery manager started
18:11:25,303 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Binding TransactionManager JNDI Reference
18:11:26,837 INFO  [EJB3Deployer] Starting java:comp multiplexer
18:11:27,744 INFO  [ServiceEndpointManager] jbossws-1.2.1.GA (build=200704151756)
18:11:28,168 WARN  [ServiceController] Problem starting service jboss.web:service=WebServer
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.JBossWeb.startService(JBossWeb.java:418)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.DynamicInterceptor.invoke(DynamicInterceptor.java:97)
        at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptor.invokeNext(SubDeployerInterceptor.java:124)
        at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptor.invoke(SubDeployerInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
        at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:435)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at $Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:302)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at $Proxy9.deploy(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:421)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:634)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner.startService(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:336)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
        at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at $Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:302)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:766)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at $Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:482)
        at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
        at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
        at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:508)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: User-specified log class 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger' cannot be found or is no
t useable.
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.discoverLogImplementation(LogFactoryImpl.java:874)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:604)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:336)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:310)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:685)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry.<clinit>(Registry.java:78)
        ... 100 more
18:11:28,542 INFO  [MailService] Mail Service bound to java:/Mail
18:11:28,630 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view META-INF/ra.xml in .../deploy/jboss-ha-local-jdbc.rar
18:11:28,658 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view META-INF/ra.xml in .../deploy/jboss-ha-xa-jdbc.rar
18:11:28,689 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view META-INF/ra.xml in .../deploy/jboss-local-jdbc.rar
18:11:28,720 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view META-INF/ra.xml in .../deploy/jboss-xa-jdbc.rar
18:11:28,749 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view META-INF/ra.xml in .../deploy/jms/jms-ra.rar
18:11:28,768 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view META-INF/ra.xml in .../deploy/quartz-ra.rar
18:11:28,774 INFO  [QuartzResourceAdapter] start quartz!!!
18:11:28,806 WARN  [ServiceController] Problem starting service jboss.jca:service=RARDeployment,name='quartz-ra.rar'
org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: User-specified log class 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger' cannot be found or is not useable.
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.discoverLogImplementation(LogFactoryImpl.java:874)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:604)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:336)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:310)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:685)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool.getLog(SimpleThreadPool.java:126)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool.initialize(SimpleThreadPool.java:247)
        at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate(StdSchedulerFactory.java:965)
        at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.getScheduler(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1152)
        at org.jboss.resource.adapter.quartz.inflow.QuartzResourceAdapter.start(QuartzResourceAdapter.java:57)
        at org.jboss.resource.deployment.RARDeployment.startService(RARDeployment.java:109)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceDynamicMBeanSupport.invoke(ServiceDynamicMBeanSupport.java:124)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:164)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
        at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at $Proxy39.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.deployment.SimpleSubDeployerSupport.startService(SimpleSubDeployerSupport.java:356)
        at org.jboss.deployment.SimpleSubDeployerSupport.start(SimpleSubDeployerSupport.java:127)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at $Proxy9.deploy(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:421)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:634)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
        at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner.startService(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:336)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
        at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at $Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:302)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:766)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at $Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:482)
        at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
        at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
        at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:508)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
18:11:29,246 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=DefaultDS' to JNDI name 'java:DefaultDS'
18:11:29,370 INFO  [A] Bound to JNDI name: queue/A
18:11:29,371 INFO  [B] Bound to JNDI name: queue/B
18:11:29,372 INFO  [C] Bound to JNDI name: queue/C
18:11:29,373 INFO  [D] Bound to JNDI name: queue/D
18:11:29,375 INFO  [ex] Bound to JNDI name: queue/ex
18:11:29,387 INFO  [testTopic] Bound to JNDI name: topic/testTopic
18:11:29,388 INFO  [securedTopic] Bound to JNDI name: topic/securedTopic
18:11:29,389 INFO  [testDurableTopic] Bound to JNDI name: topic/testDurableTopic
18:11:29,391 INFO  [testQueue] Bound to JNDI name: queue/testQueue
18:11:29,400 INFO  [UILServerILService] JBossMQ UIL service available at : /127.0.0.1:8093
18:11:29,423 INFO  [DLQ] Bound to JNDI name: queue/DLQ
18:11:29,482 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=ConnectionFactoryBinding,name=JmsXA' to JNDI name 'java:JmsXA'
18:11:29,486 ERROR [URLDeploymentScanner] Incomplete Deployment listing:

--- Packages waiting for a deployer ---
org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@12c65ccb { url=file:/D:/JBoss/jboss/server/default/deploy/jboss-web.deployer/ROOT.war/ }
  deployer: null
  status: Starting
  state: INIT_WAITING_DEPLOYER
  watch: file:/D:/JBoss/jboss/server/default/deploy/jboss-web.deployer/ROOT.war/
  altDD: null
  lastDeployed: 1316099488153
  lastModified: 1184332162000
  mbeans:

org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@5c97f632 { url=file:/D:/JBoss/jboss/server/default/deploy/http-invoker.sar/invoker.war/ }
  deployer: null
  status: Starting
  state: INIT_WAITING_DEPLOYER
  watch: file:/D:/JBoss/jboss/server/default/deploy/http-invoker.sar/invoker.war/
  altDD: null
  lastDeployed: 1316099488168
  lastModified: 1184332052000
  mbeans:

org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@c7ccf4bc { url=file:/D:/JBoss/jboss/server/default/deploy/jbossws.sar/jbossws-context.war }
  deployer: null
  status: Starting
  state: INIT_WAITING_DEPLOYER
  watch: file:/D:/JBoss/jboss/server/default/deploy/jbossws.sar/jbossws-context.war
  altDD: null
  lastDeployed: 1316099488168
  lastModified: 1316099487644
  mbeans:

org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@a9d4623e { url=file:/D:/JBoss/jboss/server/default/deploy/jms/jbossmq-httpil.sar/jbossmq-httpil.war/ }
  deployer: null
  status: Starting
  state: INIT_WAITING_DEPLOYER
  watch: file:/D:/JBoss/jboss/server/default/deploy/jms/jbossmq-httpil.sar/jbossmq-httpil.war/
  altDD: null
  lastDeployed: 1316099488168
  lastModified: 1184332094000
  mbeans:

org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@27182c4d { url=file:/D:/JBoss/jboss/server/default/deploy/management/console-mgr.sar/web-console.war/ }
  deployer: null
  status: Starting
  state: INIT_WAITING_DEPLOYER
  watch: file:/D:/JBoss/jboss/server/default/deploy/management/console-mgr.sar/web-console.war/
  altDD: null
  lastDeployed: 1316099488168
  lastModified: 1184332160000
  mbeans:

org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@2153b099 { url=file:/D:/JBoss/jboss/server/default/deploy/jmx-console.war/ }
  deployer: null
  status: null
  state: INIT_WAITING_DEPLOYER
  watch: file:/D:/JBoss/jboss/server/default/deploy/jmx-console.war/
  altDD: null
  lastDeployed: 1316099489485
  lastModified: 1184332166000
  mbeans:

--- Incompletely deployed packages ---
org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@2153b099 { url=file:/D:/JBoss/jboss/server/default/deploy/jmx-console.war/ }
  deployer: null
  status: null
  state: INIT_WAITING_DEPLOYER
  watch: file:/D:/JBoss/jboss/server/default/deploy/jmx-console.war/
  altDD: null
  lastDeployed: 1316099489485
  lastModified: 1184332166000
  mbeans:

--- MBeans waiting for other MBeans ---
ObjectName: jboss.web:service=WebServer
  State: FAILED
  Reason: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
  I Depend On:
    jboss.security:service=JaasSecurityManager
    jboss:service=TransactionManager
    jboss.jca:service=CachedConnectionManager
  Depends On Me:
    jboss.ws:service=WebServiceDeployerJSE
    jboss.mq:service=InvocationLayer,type=HTTP

ObjectName: jboss.mq:service=InvocationLayer,type=HTTP
  State: CONFIGURED
  I Depend On:
    jboss.mq:service=Invoker
    jboss.web:service=WebServer

ObjectName: jboss.jca:service=RARDeployment,name='quartz-ra.rar'
  State: FAILED
  Reason: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: User-specified log class 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger' cannot be found or is not
 useable.

--- MBEANS THAT ARE THE ROOT CAUSE OF THE PROBLEM ---
ObjectName: jboss.jca:service=RARDeployment,name='quartz-ra.rar'
  State: FAILED
  Reason: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: User-specified log class 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger' cannot be found or is not
 useable.

ObjectName: jboss.web:service=WebServer
  State: FAILED
  Reason: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
  I Depend On:
    jboss.security:service=JaasSecurityManager
    jboss:service=TransactionManager
    jboss.jca:service=CachedConnectionManager
  Depends On Me:
    jboss.ws:service=WebServiceDeployerJSE
    jboss.mq:service=InvocationLayer,type=HTTP


18:11:29,587 INFO  [Server] JBoss (MX MicroKernel) [4.2.1.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_1_GA date=200707131605)] Started in 6s:577ms
```

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you had a more descriptive title.

Comment: see my updated answer, give it a try. hope it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved... I was using newer JDK update (jdk1.6.0_25). Switching to older update helped. Now I am using jdk1.6.0_07 but I think it works with *_20 too.

Answer (score 0):

```
User-specified log class 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger' cannot be found or is no
t useable.
```

from this exception, jboss cannot find the commons-logging jar. You may check if the jar is in your WAR/EAR library directory or if the jar exists in jboss's lib dir.

-- **update** --

take a look this ticket:
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-7117
it is fixed in version 6.

you could try :
change file:
JBOSS_HOME/server/< servername>/deployers/jbossweb.deployer/META-INF/**war-deployers-jboss-beans.xml**

```
<property name="filteredPackages">javax.servlet,org.apache.commons.logging</property>

    to 

<property name="filteredPackages">javax.servlet</property>

(remove the logging package.)
```